# Stack Overflow migrating to HTTPS breaks automated leaderboards. Should we fix existing leaderboards?

Tags: bug, status-completed, leaderboard

Example of automated leaderboard:

[Make your language unusable](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/61115/make-your-language-unusable)

Stack Overflow now by default loads as HTTPS. This means that the existing snippet is broken, because it tries to request a http resource from a https page, and as such triggers a Mixed Content warning. Fixing the snippet requires changing the protocol of the 2 url functions from http to https. I have already verified that this solution works, but was unable to implement it anywhere because I do not have the required privilege.

The problem is that this script is used in many questions to automatically generate the leaderboard, and in each question it is duplicated. Fixing this would require a ton of effort, and while having this leaderboard is useful, I'm not sure whether fixing it for all questions is worth it.

Note that this does not have anything to do with api.stackExchange not accepting any http requests. The problem is the mixed content warnings that prevent cross-protocol requests.

Comment: @MartinEnder Don't do that. If we're on HTTPS, use it. https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, they should be fixed.

Considering that all other URLs on the site are being moved to HTTPS, it makes sense that we move the ones the get missed because they are part of a snippet.

They should be changed from `http://` to `https://`.